# Performance of mbedTLS sha256 realistic?

Tags: c, stm32, mbedtls

At the moment I test the sha256 performance of mbedTLS on a stm32f7 nucleo board. I measure the elapsed cycles of the stm32 board with the `cycle counter register`. The formula of measurement looks something like this:

```
DWT->CYCCNT = 0;
uint32_t dwtStart = DWT->CYCCNT;
//uncomment for mbed calculation mbedtls_sha256();
//uncomment for atecc508a calculation atecc508a_sha256();
uint32_t dwtStop = DWT->CYCCNT;
double dStart = (double) dwtStart;
double dStop = (double) dwtStop;
// SystemCoreClock is a constant = 216000000
double result_in_milliseconds = (dStop-Start)/SystemCoreClock * 1000;
```

I've testet the `sha` command on a on a microchip atecc508a which performs hardware hashing and it takes about `18ms` to hash 32 Byte of data.

With the mbedTLS in only takes about `0.05ms` to hash 32 Byte of data in software.

I know that I have to keep in mind, that a communication via i2c takes additional time for an operation, but are these results even legit? Could there be such a discrepancy between those two operations?

Both operations return the corresponding hash to a certain input of 32 Bytes.

Would be really thankful, if someone could answer my question.

Comment: As an embedded developer, there's absolutely no point in doing that computation as `double`s, even on your honking big F7.

Comment: Also, that is 10,800 clock cycles, which is not totally unreasonable but I'm not familiar enough with the algorithm to say for sure.

Comment: @unwind You are absolutly right! I've rounded the results for better readability next time I will provide the correct values. My mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At standard I2C speed (100kbit/s) you can transfer

> 0.018*100000 = 1800 bit = 225 byte

in 18ms (*including* overhead). This is not a whole lot, so yes, it seems reasonable that most of the time is used up by the i2c communication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate it!